# Proving $e$ is irrational

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been working on a proof of the irrationality of $e$. I was thinking that
this would move in a similar routine to proving that the square root of a
prime number is irrational, but I think that routine might be a little
overdone. I want to try and prove it in a manner that deals with the expansion
of $e = \frac{1}{0!} + \frac{1}{1!} + \frac{1}{2!} + ... 
= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}.$ If I assume this sum is rational, will
I run into some contradictory properties related to the sum of an infinite
series?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_e_is_irrational

Comment: Essentially, it is enough to show that $(n!)e$ is never an integer.